# Missing return in a function expected to return 'Room'

Tags: func

```
    func getRoomById(id: Int?) -> Room {
            //void change Room ?
            for room in allRooms {
                if room.id == id {
                    return room
                }
            }
        }
```

Why this case I have this problem ? I want get room with id (Int). I have a building,floor,flat and room.

Comment: What if no room in `allRooms` has the requested id? You still need to return something in that case (which you currently don't do)

Comment: I have private(set) var allRooms = [Room]()

Comment: That doesn't answer my comment. You cannot guarantee at compile time that the function will only be called with an id that exists in that array. Therefore the compiler requires you to `return` *something* in case that `if` never evaluates to true

Comment: Аny suggestions you can give me?

Comment: IMO the most logical solution would be to change the return type to `Room?` and have a `return nil` after the `for` loop